# Error on trying to connect to SOAP service

Tags: php, laravel, soap

I'm trying to consume the "search" function of the Brazilian CADSUS service, but I get the following error:

`"Forced circuit exception";`

Right below, I have the following code, which uses Laravel 5.6 and PHP 7.1

```
Route::get('/ws/teste', function () {
    try {
        $opts = array(
            'http' => array(
                'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
            )
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $wsdlUrl = 'https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cadsus/CadsusService/v5r0?wsdl';
        $soapClientOptions = array(
            'trace' => 1,
            'stream_context' => $context,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'Username' => '*****',
            'Password' => '*****'
        );
        $client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);
        $parameters = array(
            'CNESUsuario' => array(
                'CNES' => '6963447',
                'Usuario' => 'LEONARDO',
                'Senha' => ''
            ),
            'FiltroPesquisa' => array(
                'nomeCompleto' => 'SERGIO ARAUJO CORREIA LIMA',
                'tipoPesquisa' => 'IDENTICA'
            ),
            'higienizar' => 0
        );
        $result = $client->pesquisar($parameters);
        print_r($result);
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    } });
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: It appears that you've just posted your username and password, you'll want to change them immediately.

Comment: @AlexHowansky those credentials are public offered by CADSUS. So, there is no problem in posting with them

Comment: Please also `echo htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse());` in your catch block.

Comment: @Furgas it prints out this xml https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I3FwmqUiULA-vqe9xRhGNcz1nYuDA3wTAZqTUTI16JU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SOAP response:

```
[cvc-minLength-valid: Value '' with length = '0' is not facet-valid with
respect to minLength '1' for type '#AnonType_SenhaCNESUsuarioType'.,
cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '' of element 'ns1:Senha' is not valid
```

So, `Senha` can't be empty string.

Comment: That was it. Now it is showing another error: "nested fault: XML parse failed: libxml error: : level: 3, code: 5, file: none, line: 1, str1: "", str2: "", str3: "", int1: 0, int2: 37, message: Extra content at the end of the document"